# Cascading drop down in SharePoint 2007 document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, document-library

I have a document library in which there are two fields.

Category
Subcategory

Both are drop downs and I want Subcategory to be displayed based on Category selected by user. It's a pretty simple functionality which you must have also seen in the form of Country/City drop down.

How do I do this in SharePoint 2007? I don't want to develop or use custom solution for this. I want to use the OOTB form through which you create a new Item in any document library.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: What are a fields types (Lookup,Choice)?

Comment: Fields type is Choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try SPServices and it's [SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation)

> The SPCascadeDropdowns function lets you set up cascading dropdowns on
>   SharePoint forms. What this means is that you can enforce hierarchical
>   relationships between column values. The function uses the
>   GetListItems operation of the Lists Web Service to refresh the
>   allowable values based on relationships which are maintained in
>   reference lists. By implementing this function, there are no coding
>   requirements to manage the hierarchical relationships (once it is in
>   place) and you can let your users manage the content in the reference
>   lists.

Comment: This looks great. Two questions. I can't seem to figure out how to use it. Do I need to use SharePoint Designer to make it work? Secondly will it also work inside Word documents which uses those fields as part of content type?

Comment: It is JavaScript library which internally uses SharePoint web services. It can be used on web forms(for example in html form webpart or content editor webpart). I don't think it will work inside word documents.